# Docker image ls does not look at the proper IP address

Tags: docker

I can see my machine … Windows 10 Home

```
usuario@DESKTOP-GTCQCAR MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker-machine ls
NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM DOCKER ERRORS
default - virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.101:2376 v18.05.0-ce
```

But when I try to list the images it tries to connect to a different IP ending in 100, instead of 101 where the docker machine is:

```
usuario@DESKTOP-GTCQCAR ~
$ docker image ls
error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.37/images/json: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

It can not connect. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this great guide: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem after updating from Docker toolbox to Docker for windows.
I solved this problem by deleting all the environment variables starting with Docker.
I am not sure if it will solve your problem as well, but may be it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be helpful

Issue can be of having **Docker Toolbox** installed before changing to **Docker for Windows**

- Uninstalled **Docker for windows** (make sure Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox are uninstalled as well)
- Go to C:\users[USER] directory and remove `.docker` directory if it is there.
- Remove Environmental Variables:

  - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
  - DOCKER_CERT_PATH
  - DOCKER_HOST
  - DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH

You might want to restart you computer just to be safe.

Reference: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-starts-but-trying-to-do-anything-results-in-error-during-connect/49007/5